# Escape a mm/dd/YY backup date in a file name

Tags: shell, filenames, date, escape-characters, slash

I have been trying to:

```
cp file.csv file.$(date +%D).csv
```

But it fails because the filenames is: `file.03/27/19.csv` with the slash of separate directories.

And I have been trying again to:

```
cp file.csv file.$(printf "%q" $(date +%D)).csv
```

But it still fails.

Comment: You can not set a filename with slash characters: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847288/is-it-possible-to-use-in-a-filename

Comment: the problem is your use of the `date` format using the `/` character. You said it yourself, the shell is seeing them as directory markers. Try one of the many other options available from `date`.  You might be able to get the / escaped so the filename uses the character code (like putting a space in a filename), but that is often problematic.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can't have `/` (byte 0x2F on ASCII-based systems) in a file name, period.

You can use characters that look like `/` like `∕` (U+2215 division slash) or `⁄` (U+2044 fraction slash though found in fewer of the charsets used in current locales), so you could do (provided that U+2215 character exists in the locale's charset, includes GBK, BIG5, UTF-8, GB18030):

```
cp file.csv "file.$(date +%D | sed 's|/|∕|g').csv"
```

Or with some shells (`zsh`, `bash` at least):

```
cp file.csv "file.$(date +%D | sed $'s|/|\u2215|g').csv"
```

(here using `sed` instead of `tr` as some `tr` implementations including GNU `tr` still don't support multi-byte characters).

But you may run into problems like the file name being rendered differently in locales using a different charset from the one that was in use at the time you created the file (and of course the confusion of users when they see what looks like a slash in a file name).

My advice would be to use the standard non-ambiguous (for most people outside the US, 03/12/18 would be interpreted as the 3<sup>rd</sup> of December  2018 for instance) YYYY-mm-dd format instead (which also helps wrt sorting):

```
cp file.csv "file.$(date +%Y-%m-%d).csv"
```

Which with many `date` implementations you can shorten to:

```
cp file.csv "file.$(date +%F).csv"
```

Comment: Other characters similar to slash can also be cumbersome to type in terminal.

Comment: @gronostaj, I've added a method to specify the character based on its Unicode codepoint.